# Script to gather IP Address and hostname from network devices

Tags: bash, shell-script, scanner

I want an output like this:

```
IP Address: 192.168.1.1
Hostname:Test-PC
```

This is what I have done:

```
test(){  
        ping -c 1 $1 > /dev/null      
        [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "IP Address": $i is online.  
}

for i in 192.168.1.{1..255}  
do  
test $i & disown  
done
```

I added this line to collect the hostname, which failed. How could I get the hostname?

```
nmap -sU --script nbstat.nse -p137 192.168.11.*
```

Comment: For the Nmap scan try `192.168.11.0/24`

Comment: Why not just use `host`, `nslookup` or `dig`?